# “ Javascript Error” appears and the button “ add number” does not work

Tags: c#, javascript, webbrowser-control

After login in Yahoo mail, I clicked in the button “account info” then another button “change”. When I want to set new number deleting the old number, I find a message “javascript error “ and then the button “add number” does not work. When I put “script error = true”, it does not give the message ““javascript error“ but the button “ add number” does not work. In spite of enabling “scripting of java applets” in the internet explorer –security section, it does not work yet.  I think that it needs to add Java script but I don’t know how to add it. windows form webbrowser not working but In internet explorer 8 or 11, both Java script and add number work successfully without any issue.

I showed my code below. I will be grateful, if you help me cordially.

```
     private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)

    {
         webBrowser1.Navigate("https://edit.yahoo.com/commchannel/manage?.scrumb=5PZ91z352Lx&.done=https%3A%2F%2Fedit.yahoo.com%2Fmc2.0%2Feval_profile%3F.intl%3Dus%26.lang%3Den-US%26.done%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fus-mg6.mail.yahoo.com%2Fneo%2Flaunch%253f.rand%3D4birl4bqm6di7%26.src%3Dcdgm%26.intl%3Dus%26.lang%3Den-US%26.scrumb%3D8oPNvGh8uNk%26.scrumb2%3DDMwGgHj%2FkoW&partner=reg&src=&.intl=us&.scrumb2=e9JtdJJkfhg#");


    }

    public void delay(int ms)
    {
        int sVal = Environment.TickCount;
        do
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        } while ((Environment.TickCount - sVal) <= (ms * 10));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {

            string strPwdchar = "123456789";
            string strPwd = "";
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                int iRandom = rnd.Next(2, strPwdchar.Length - 3);
                strPwd += strPwdchar.Substring(iRandom, 2);
            }

            random.Text = strPwd;

        }


        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", username.Text);
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("passwd").SetAttribute("value", pass.Text);
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(".save").InvokeMember("click"); delay(1000);
        // add phone number 
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("addPhone").InvokeMember("click"); delay(100);
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mobilephone").SetAttribute("value", "155" + random.Text); delay(100);
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("savePhLink").InvokeMember("click"); delay(600);
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("yui-gen1-button").InvokeMember("click"); delay(500);
        // delete
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mdelete1").InvokeMember("click"); delay(500);
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("yui-gen2-button").InvokeMember("click"); delay(500);
        // signout
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("yui_3_4_1_1_1409000971385_67").InvokeMember("click"); delay(500);


    }
}
```

Comment: Out of interest are you trying to write a not to mass register yahoo email accounts?

Comment: no I am doing this for other purpose. It's just I am show sample link same process I am doing my other site.

Comment: my client need other site purpose but same problem like yahoo. that's why I am need solution for this issue. I am not doing anything in yahoo.